# How can I redirect users when they follow a link directly to a certain file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site uses php and htaccess.

Basically, I have a file (example.com/music.mp3) and I don't want anyone to access it directly unless they are coming from a specific page (example.com/music.php).

Also, if they try and access it directly, I want it to redirect them to the page.

Is there any way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

> For clarity:
>
> Case 1: User clicks a link to the mp3 file from an external forum and they're redirected to the php file.
>
> Case 2: User clicks the link to the mp3 file from the appropriate page and they get to download / listen to it freely.

Comment: You can always accept of reject the request depending on the value of the HTTP referrer (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), but since the value is filled client-side, it can be faked, making it an unreliable way to protect a resource.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^music.mp3$ http://www.example.com/music.php [R,L]
```

If you want to allow blank referers, add this rule first:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I tried it and it worked but then it stopped working.

Here's what I did:
1) Clicked the link to the file on the page and it started downloading. Good.
2) Tried accessing the file directly and it redirected me to the page. Good.
3) Tried clicking the link on the redirected page only to see that it redirected to the page again and not the file. Oh noes.

Comment: Change my first ``RewriteCond`` to this: ``RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/music.php [NC]``

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the `<if>` and `<else>` directive.

```
<if "%{HTTP_REFERER} == 'example.com'">
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/music.mp3 [R=301,NC,L]
</if>
<else>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/music.php [R=301,NC,L]
</else>
```

So if the referrer is equal to example.com, then redirect to `/music.mp3` - if not then redirect to `/music.php`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Answer (score 0):

What about having `music.php` to read `music.mp3` and return it? Trusting HTTP_REFERER is not error-proof. Some people will have blank referer, and as soon as someone discovers that you use HTTP_REFERER to allow download, word will spread and your users will begin to use fake headers.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$filename = 'music.mp3';
if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {
    // user is authenticated
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename))
    readfile($filename);
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

I have a system where people have to be logged in to download some pdf reports. They receive a link pointing to a php file. The PHP file determines if the user is logged in, and if they are, I send a Content type of `application/pdf` and use `readfile` to send the file to the user.

Just make **very sure** to sanitize `$filename` if this is being sent by the client, or the client will be able to read almost any file from your system.

Comment: I don't have a login system on my site. I just want to make sure people aren't directly linking to certain files from their blogs / forums. Is there a way to do this without user authentication in php?

Comment: There's no really a way to make sure people don't hotlink you data on their sites. They can put a link, people copy and paste, and download. Or they use `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />` on their pages, and you will get blank referers.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 100% protection, just a general method to block people haphazardly linking directly to the file via social media, etc.